# How to understand the following limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am an beginner and calculating the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \left(\frac{e^x-e^{\sin x}}{x-\sin x}\right)$$

The correct answer is $1$ but I cannot understand it:
If $x$ is close to $0$, then $e^x = 1$, $e^{\sin x} = 1$, $x = 0$ and $\sin x = 0$.

Aren't we dealing with $\left(\frac{0}{0}\right)$? How to get $1$?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Thanks for your replies, now I can solve it!
Indeed, when x->0, we are dealing with $\left(\frac{0}{0}\right)$, so we need to apply L' Hopital's Rule: assume $t = x - \sin x$,

$$e^{\sin x} \frac{(e^t - e^0)'}{(t - 0)'}  = e^{\sin x}\frac{e^t - 0}{1 - 0} $$
when x->0 then t->0 so $$e^{\sin x}\frac{e^t - 0}{1 - 0} = e^{sin0}\frac{1-0}{1} = 1$$

Comment: Do you know about derivatives?

Comment: `If x is close to 0, then e^x =0` No, it's close to $e^0=1$. `Aren't we dealing with 0/0 ?` Yes, indeed. How do you know to solve such limits in general?

Comment: @dxiv sorry I $e^0 = 1$ my bad.. I saw some simple examples but this limit seems different..

Comment: Did you learn [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) yet?

Comment: @Infinite Monkey  Thanks for your reply! Now I know how to deal with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can factor $e^{\sin x}$ out of the numerator to get
$$ e^{\sin x} \left( \frac{e^{x - \sin x} - 1}{x - \sin x} \right)$$ and write $t = x - \sin x$ to further get $$e^{\sin x} \left( \frac{e^t - e^0}{t - 0} \right).$$

As $x \to 0$ you also have $t \to 0$ so by continuity and some limit laws the limit equals $$e^{\sin 0} \cdot \left. \frac{d}{dt} e^t  \right|_{t=0} = e^{\sin 0} \cdot e^0 = 1.$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But sorry I don't know about derivatives..When x->0, you write $e^{sin0}$, but when t->0, you do derivatives..why do not write (e^0-e^0)/(0-0)? What is the different? Can you please explain more?   Thank you very much..

Comment: If you don't know derivatives (and perhaps not L'Hospital rule) then what are the rules we can use?

Comment: I think this is the right approach.  Note you don't have to use derivative, but just the standard $e$ limit in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using the l'Hospital's rule 3 times, it results in 1:

$$\lim_\limits{x\to0}\frac{e^x-e^{\sin{x}}}{x-\sin{x}}\stackrel{l'H}=\lim_\limits{x\to0}\frac{e^x-e^{\sin{x}}\cos{x}}{1-\cos{x}}\stackrel{l'H}=\lim_\limits{x\to0}\frac{e^x-e^{\sin{x}}\cos^2{x}+e^{\sin{x}}\sin{x}}{\sin{x}}\stackrel{l'H}=\lim_\limits{x\to0}\frac{e^x-e^{\sin{x}}\cos^3{x}+e^{\sin{x}}\sin{2x}+0.5e^{\sin{x}}\sin{2x}+e^{\sin{x}}\cos{x}}{\cos{x}}=\frac{1-1+0+0+1}{1}=1.$$